# Python Sqlite question mark problem while inserting

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to write an Sqlite Python code and have a problem with the question marks. I want to insert some columns into the `table_name229` with headers of `columns`. The rows are in the `rows` list. When I input `(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` instead of `{entry}` it works fine but becomes manual. So, I wanted to input those question marks as follows to automate the process, but of course, it throws the below error.

```
c.executemany("""INSERT INTO {tablename} {headers}
                VALUES {entry}""".format(tablename='table_name229',headers=tuple(columns),
                                        entry=tuple(['?']*len(columns))),rows)
```

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 7 supplied.

Can you please help resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple of strings, when converted into its string representation by the `str.format` method, becomes a comma-delimited list of single-quoted strings enclosed in parentheses, which happens to work well for header names, but not for question mark placeholders, which are not supposed to be quoted since they would otherwise be treated as plain string values.

You should instead build a comma-delimited list of question marks enclosed in parentheses on your own with the `str.join` method:

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO {tablename} {headers} VALUES ({entry})'.format(
    tablename='table_name229', headers=tuple(columns),
    entry=','.join(['?'] * len(columns))), rows)
```